# Python script db password

Tags: python, sql-server, bash

I need a script in python that changes the password of an mysql db. How can I do this? 
I can also use bash comands.

Something like this:

```
os.system('some console code')
```

thank you

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: No sorry I got confused its MySQL Server I'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to use the [MYSQLdb](http://mysql-python.blogspot.com.au/) module.

You could then use [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html) as part of a query to make the change.

If you must use the command line as per your request (and not another module) then you could try using subprocess.open and call mysql from a command line:

```
mysql -u [username] -p -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'user' = PASSWORD ('newpassword')"
```